# Spring Data Rest : How to expose a json schema from a repository (2.0.0.M1)

Tags: spring-data-rest

I saw in the source code that Spring DATA Rest can expose a Json Schema for a repository with this URL : /{repository}/schema.

Is there anybody who know how to configure this ?

There is the RepositorySchemaController (org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc) but i have not found how to use it.

version : 2.0.0.M1

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you set the right headers...

```
Request -  /{repository}/schema
Header - Accept: application/json+schema
```

Also if you haven't looked into 2.0 snapshots, there are lot more features and changes coming up

**EDIT: Jan 27 2014**

***Correction:***
Accept should be "`application/schema+json`" instead of "`application/json+schema`"

```
Request -  /{repository}/schema
Header - Accept: application/schema+json
```

Comment: I try this :
`curl -v -H "Accept: application/json+schema" http://localhost:8989/books/schema`

But i have this exception :
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Comment: I suggest you try snapshots rather milestones since the dependencies have been changed along with code

Comment: I just found the reason for my issue. It's painful :-)
The correct header is application/schema+json, not json+schema. It works now, thank you for your help.

Comment: My mistake and good catch! Going to update answer just in case someone else runs into this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Just an update for version `2.4.0` of Spring Data REST:

JSONSchema is now exposed under the `profile` link, so you need to change your request as follows:

```
Request:  /profile/{repository}
Header:   Accept: application/schema+json
```

You can find the updated documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#metadata.json-schema).

Answer (score 0):

This actually returns the [ALPS style](http://alps.io) representation. If you are interested in other formats, e.g. [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/), you might want to add your own controller to be flexible:

```
@BasePathAwareController
public class JsonSchemaController {

  public static final String PROFILE_ROOT_MAPPING = "/schema";

  public static final String RESOURCE_PROFILE_MAPPING = PROFILE_ROOT_MAPPING + "/{repository}";

  @RequestMapping(value = RESOURCE_PROFILE_MAPPING, method = GET)
  public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> descriptor(RootResourceInformation information) {
    SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder configBuilder = new SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder(
        SchemaVersion.DRAFT_2019_09, OptionPreset.PLAIN_JSON);
    SchemaGeneratorConfig config = configBuilder.build();
    SchemaGenerator generator = new SchemaGenerator(config);
    JsonNode jsonSchema = generator.generateSchema(information.getPersistentEntity().getType());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(jsonSchema);
  }

}
```

Dependencies for [Snow](https://github.com/ssilverman/snowy-json):

```
implementation 'com.github.victools:jsonschema-generator:4.16.0'
```

Comment: It returns ALPS style by default, but if you provide the `Accept: application/schema+json` Header, it will return JSON Schema instead.