# Spring data rest json schema

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have a REST web service with spring-data-rest 2.1.0.RELEASE working great and I would like to develop a CRUD web client for it. But instead of creating a client that would only work with the current state of my web service I thought, how great would it be if my client could adapt to my web service. And of course someone else thought about this already :), here are a few examples:

- http://weluse.github.io/hyperagent-forms/
- https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor

Most of the projects I found, related to creating forms dynamically revolve around http://json-schema.org which I'm not sure spring-data-rest supports. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169937/spring-data-rest-how-to-expose-a-json-schema-from-a-repository-2-0-0-m1/21191209#21191209) question which suggests SDR does support exposing json schema of it's resources. And indeed if I use 'Accept: application/schema+json' the resulting data changes a bit but it still does not present me with things like required properties and data types etc.

So the questions:

1. Is spring data rest capable of generating information like required
   properties and validations constraints (min, max, etc.) of it's
   resources?, how ?.
2. If not, are there any plans on implementing this
   ?.
3. If not, could someone point me to the correct way of overriding
   the handler for a specific mime type for example
   "application/schema+json" so I can respond with the data I need?

Comment: The /resource/schema representation does not confirm to HAL which SDR is based on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, silly me. Looks like SDR does support schema+json. I was just asking on the wrong URI, you have to add a /schema/ to the item collection when asking for the schema. Like this:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/schema+json" http://localhost:8080/items/schema/
```

And that's all.

Comment: You would soon realize the response is not based on HAL :)

Comment: Hi @Stackee007, thanks for your comments. I know this is not based on HAL. But it does gives me, more or less, what I need which is information about the resources so I can dynamically generate a form and validate it on the client. AFAIK HAL does not provide this kind of metadata, if it does I would love to know how. I still plan to use HAL to transfer the data itself though.