# Spring Data Rest: How can I make a json schema property required?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema, spring-data-rest

From reading [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169937/spring-data-rest-how-to-expose-a-json-schema-from-a-repository-2-0-0-m1), I learned that Spring Data Rest exposes a JSON schema at: `/{resourceName}/schema`. Ex:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/members/schema
Accept : application/schema+json
```

```
{
    "name": "org.jxc876.model.Member",
    "description": "rest.description.member",
    "links": [],
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "long",
            "description": "rest.description.member.id",
            "required": false
        },
        "alias": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "rest.description.member.alias",
            "required": false
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "rest.description.member.name",
            "required": false
        }
    }
}
```

I want to indicate that certain fields are required. I initially tried using Bean Validation annotations (@NotNull) and Jackson (@JacksonProperty) annotations but neither seemed to trigger the flag.

Note: I am using Spring Data Rest 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the source code, and found:

- [RepositorySchemaController](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositorySchemaController.java) - maps to /{repository}/schema
- [PersistentEntityToJsonSchemaConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/json/PersistentEntityToJsonSchemaConverter.java#L83)

  - contains a convert(Object, TypeDescriptor, TypeDescriptor) method which creates the Json schema
  - Uses another class [JsonSchema](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/json/JsonSchema.java) and its nested inner class (Property)
  - The Property contains 3 fields: type, description, **required**
  - It looks like the constructor call is hardcoded to always use false: `new Property(type, message, false)`

I'm thinking I should extend PersistentEntityToJsonSchemaConverter and override the convert method, then also override the controller and call my custom JsonSchemaConverter.

Comment: The schema generated by SDR does not conform JSON Schema. However there is [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-354) request to support JSON Schema and Hyper Schema which is the right way to go. I suggest you vote/comment on the ticket to push it up the queue.

Comment: Hello Mike, did you try that? If so, please tell us your experiences, whether this was possible or not.